# How C indexes works for integers in the C

Tags: c, gcc, clang

in the online course from my university I met the next interesting fact:

The executing of the next line will produce `'\0'`:

`5["Peklo"]`

I also tried some different examples by passing different integers and string literals. I know that C strings are `const char *` pointers therefore that code is valid and will compile, but I can not figure out how the output calculates/depends on the passing integer value of the string indexer. If someone knows, can you explain to me in detail why `0["P"]`, `0["A"]` and `1["A"]` produces different results (80, 65, 0)?

Comment: Does it help if I tell you that `a[b]` is the same as `b[a]`? i.e. `5["Peklo"]` is the same as `"Peklo"[5]`

Comment: The expression `a[i]` is defined as `*(a + i)` - given an address `a`, offset `i` elements and dereference the result.  Addition is commutative: `a + i == i + a`, so `a[i] == *(a + i) == *(i + a) == i[a]`.

Comment: @JohnBode `float a[] = { NAN,NAN,NAN,NAN}; if(a[3]!=3[a]){puts("False");}` will print `False`. `a[i] == *(a + i) == *(i + a) == i[a]` is not always true. What is always true is that `&(a[i]) == &(*(a + i)) == &(*(i + a)) == &(i[a])`, as long as no UB is involved.

Comment: @JohnBode well, now it makes sense... I did not look from that perspective.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
5["Peklo"]  === "Peklo"[5] == (char[]){'P','e','k','l','o','0'}[5] == 0 == '\0'
                                       [0] [1] [2] [3] [4] [5]
```

Comment: Wait, really? We can take reversely chars from string by swapping values before and in the bracket squares?

Comment: @Jeidoz I do not see any reverse here